# ScrollTo function scrolls past element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollto

I have this simple contact form set up and, since I don't have the development time at this moment, I set this one up using jQuery verification instead of AJAX. This works fine.

But now I would like to have the page scroll down when there are errors in the form. I've downloaded jquery.scrollTo.js and added it to my header.php file. And I have the following script for the `scrollTo`:

```
if ($("#front_page_contactformulier span").hasClass("error")) {
    $('body').scrollTo('#fp_content_006',4000);
}
```

Now the weird thing is, when the `#front_page_contactformulier span` has class `error` it scrolls past this element (like literally to the bottom of the page).

If I change the script to another element:

```
if ($("#front_page_contactformulier span").hasClass("error")) {
    $('body').scrollTo('#fp_content_005',4000);
}
```

It works?

I cant for the life of me find out why this is happening? Here is my full code:

HTML

```
<section id="fp_content_006">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <article>
                <?php if( get_field('koptekst_6') ): ?>
                    <h2><?php the_field('koptekst_6'); ?></h2>
                    <div style="display:block;height:2px;width:30px;background:#f60;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:15px;"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( get_field('content_koptekst_6') ): ?>
                    <?php the_field('content_koptekst_6'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="front_page_contactformulier">
                    <span class="error">Error</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
#fp_content_006 {
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:90px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:90px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
if ($("#front_page_contactformulier span").hasClass("error")) {
    $('body').scrollTo('#fp_content_006',4000);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjn845wj/), and the super weird thing is, it works here.

Comment: Did you check the rendered dom? Is the element  on the bottom?

Comment: It's done using the submit button of the form, If you click on submit, the errors appear. But the page doesn't automatically scrolls back to the form to show the errors. Thats why I'm doing it like this for now.

Comment: Does jsFiddle process PHP?

Comment: Your PHP code is useless to us. Cause an error on the page, Right Click > Inspect Element > Copy + Paste the *rendered* HTML from there rather than the PHP that's creating it.

Comment: I don't think so, thats why I removed the `php` file in the code.

Comment: @Santi: The php code is just a simple form. Nothing fancy. My question isn't related to the php code. But with the scroll function and why it scrolls past the `section element`. I can remove the php code from the question but the question it self will remain the same.

Comment: The issue with your code could be related to the HTML that you're outputting, thus why I'm suggesting you show us that instead of the PHP.

Comment: I removed the `php` part from the question. If I do the same in my file it still scrolls past the element. Thats why it doesn't really matter what the php file outputs... (so i thought).

Comment: @Jay-oh There is still more PHP code in your question; have you tried removing all of it from your file, just for testing's sake?

Comment: @freginold: Yeah. Just did that. Did not make a difference.

Comment: The css is different for id **fp_content_006** in the fiddle and one the mentioned above.

Comment: @user3888958: Yeah, that was for fiddle purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your **jquery.scrollTo.js** is included properly in **header.php** file and remember this from PHP documentation:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

You can find documentation [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: It is. It does work if I point to another element. Only not the `006` content part. Also, if I include the form in the file (place the form code it self) it still scrolls past the element. So I don't believe it's something with the `include php` code

Answer (score 0):

According to the JS you posted, let me break it down for you

```
if ($("#front_page_contactformulier span").hasClass("error")) {
    $('body').scrollTo('#fp_content_006',4000);
}
```

The first argument should be the Jquery Object and you just need to wrap your selector with jquery object like this:

```
    $('body').scrollTo($('#fp_content_006'),4000);
```

As per documentation provided [here](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo), you have plenty other ways to scroll instead of selector.

You can find the demo [here](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Also would like to mention, 4000 is the duration of animation which seems to be pretty high, i would recommend it to be 300 to 800.

Comment: You are correct. There are more way's to scroll to the element. I can use pixels, but not all screens have the same pixels so I will have to change that. The `4000` is just there for the testing...